# Ubuntu 15.10 installed on MacBook won't shut down properly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my MacBook using rEFIt, and the problem is now it won't shut down properly. Every time it reaches the very last part where it's about to power off and then just hangs. Before installing Ubuntu 15.10, I had 14.04 installed, but I accidentally let aptitude uninstall some important packages while trying to install the trackpad driver, and I was unable to boot into it anymore. Thus, I had to go into recovery mode and install 15.10 (by overwriting the old installation) from usb. However, now when I open my computer to the refit screen, I see two bootloaders for Ubuntu. One is located at

```
EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

and the other is located at

```
boot\vmlinuz-4.2.0-19-generic.efi.signed
```

If I choose the first one, I just get a black screen (I'm assuming this is from the 14.04 installation which was erased), and when I use the second one I can boot and use ubuntu just fine, but I can never shut down properly. What should I do to fix this issue? If there is any other information I can include please let me know, thank you.